# Change saving location for jupyter notebook checkpoints

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to change the location where the jupyter notebooks checkpoints are saved? Or in other words, use a different location for the 'ipynb_checkpoints" folder?

I have several notebooks saved on a network drive, but would rather have the checkpoints save on a local drive as sometimes when working from home my VPN connection is patchy and I loose access to the network.